# SQL Server: How to auto compile table in insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can auto compile a table when: a user is inserting or modifying the data in a certain column so if he do, the other column is unable or setted NULL.

For example if an user insert Value1 he can't insert Value2 cause is setted to NULL or if he compile Value2 he can't insert the Value1.
If he insert Value1 or Value2 in update or is not possible or the other Value is automatic setted to NULL.

```
   Value  Value1  Value2
     1     'abc'   NULL
     2     NULL    'cde'
     3     NULL    'fgh'
```

Comment: You can handle such logic in Insert or UpdateTriggers accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,
    [value1] [int] NULL,
    [Value2] [int] NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test]  WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Test] CHECK  
    (([Value1] IS NOT NULL AND [Value2] IS NULL OR
      [Value1] IS NULL AND [Value2] IS NOT NULL))
```

The results of the following inserts are:

**Failure: The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_Test".**

```
INSERT INTO Test
VALUES
(1,1,1)
```

**Success:**

```
INSERT INTO Test
VALUES
(1,NULL,1)
```

**Success:**

```
INSERT INTO Test
VALUES
(1,1,NULL)
```

**Failure: The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_Test".**

```
INSERT INTO Test
VALUES
(1,NULL,NULL)
```

Comment: @Vladmyr no problem, you can accept this as the answer if it  worked for you and you think it will help people in the future.